# Using an image for a list item that is not a link

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<footer id="footer">
    <ul id="labels">
        <li id="label1">About</li>
        <li id="label2"><a href="">blah</a></li>
        <li id="label3"><a href="">blah</a></li>
        <li id="label4"><a href="">blah</a></li>
        <li id="label5"><a href="">blah</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

I know how to specify an image for `li` items 2-5 but not sure how to for `label1`?

I have the following `CSS` but it only works when `label1` has the `<a href="">` tag. Is there any way to do it the way I am trying to and if not how should I approach it?

```
#label1 a { 
    height:9px; 
    width:43px; 
    background: url(/Content/images/footer/about.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
    padding:0; 
}
```

Sorry I'm very new to CSS/HTML

Comment: @MrLister clearly tried what's in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#label1 { /* I've edited this rule */
    height: 9px;
    width: 43px;
    background: url(/Content/images/footer/about.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

remove the `a` bit. It makes you select the `<a>` element within `#label1`. But because you want to apply these rules to `#label1`, you only have to remove the `a` selector.

Comment: Thanks Tim. I had wondered what the a part was for and this has massively cleared a lot of things up for me.

Comment: What I was going to say but was too slow =/

Comment: @Relequestual I know how it feels... Better luck next time haha

Comment: @TimS.People seem to be so blommin quick! Thinking about using the SO query stuff to find out when people are less active at answering questions so I stand a better chance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS's list-style-image for each of the labels

```css
li#label1{ list-style-image:url('img1.jpg'); }
li#label2{ list-style-image:url('img2.jpg'); }
li#label3{ list-style-image:url('img3.jpg'); }
li#label4{ list-style-image:url('img4.jpg'); }
li#label5{ list-style-image:url('img5.jpg'); }
li#label6{ list-style-image:url('img6.jpg'); }
```

Comment: @VivekChandra Whats the problem exactly ?

Comment: the problem is that you havnt read the question.. he wants the css for `label1` and only `label1` not the whole set!!

Comment: @VivekChandra Are you serious?! I think you haven't read my answer completely. He could use just the first row (its called an example, my friend). Plus - it generally makes more sense to use list-style-image when you need to add bullets to `li` items, and not background-image. Both work, but in my personal beliefe `list-style-image` is a more "correct" solution as it actually describes the markup better.